# Azure Functions Shared DLLs in root /bin not found

Tags: c#, azure, dll, azure-functions

Based on the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-reference-csharp/) and a [response](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c73971d3-3de6-4cac-882c-4bfdaec50d92/share-dlls-between-functions-in-a-functions-app?forum=AzureFunctions) I got on the MS forums.

I should be able to reference my own libraries in a root bin folder in my Azure Functions App. I will be sharing these libraries between multiple functions.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
#r "../bin/AquasolConnect.Connector.dll"
#r "../bin/AquasolConnect.TankLinkConnector.dll"

using System;
using AquasolConnect.Connector;
using AquasolConnect.TankLinkConnector;

public static void Run(TimerInfo GetTankReadingsTimer, TraceWriter log)
```

Here is my folder structure:

- root

  - bin

    - AquasolConnect.Connector.dll
    - AquasolConnect.TankLinkConnector.dll
  - GetTankReadings

    - functions.json
    - run.csx

Here is what the log says:

> 2016-04-22T11:44:56.914 (1,1): error CS0006: Metadata file
>   '../bin/AquasolConnect.Connector.dll' could not be found
>
> 2016-04-22T11:44:56.914 (2,1): error CS0006: Metadata file
>   '../bin/AquasolConnect.TankLinkConnector.dll' could not be found
>
> 2016-04-22T11:44:56.914 (5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace
>   name 'AquasolConnect' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> 2016-04-22T11:44:56.914 (6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace
>   name 'AquasolConnect' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing the "..\bin" portion of your paths

Comment: I was able to get the function to compile, but only by using the full file reference.  
  
#r "D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\AquasolConnect.Connector.dll"  
#r "D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\AquasolConnect.TankLinkConnector.dll"  
  
But then when the function ran I got:  
  
Unable to find assembly 'AquasolConnect.TankLinkConnector, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Are you missing a private assembly file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get the function to compile, but only by using the full file reference.

```
#r "D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\AquasolConnect.Connector.dll"  
#r "D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\AquasolConnect.TankLinkConnector.dll"
```

But then when the function ran I got:

> Unable to find assembly 'AquasolConnect.TankLinkConnector,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Are you
>   missing a private assembly file?

Better answers anyone?

Comment: Andrew, I'll be looking at this issue and posting an update on this soon.

Comment: Andrew, unfortunately there's currently a defect with the "shared assembly files" scenario, which is particularly impactful with indirect dependencies. I have opened an issue for this and will have an fix soon (https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/305). I'll post here again as we make progress on this (i'm also liking the issue so you can follow there if you'd like).

Comment: Andrew, I'm sorry the turn around wasn't as quick on this, but this fix has now been deployed. Let me know if you have any additional problems.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like things might be working but I cannot confirm because a new issue has popped up. I am not getting "Method not found: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation.Retrieve(System.String, System.String)'" errors.

I have the following references in the function.

Comment: See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8f70fb3c-ad60-4cb4-be7a-a8b46c95ce8c/method-not-found-microsoftwindowsazurestoragetabletableoperationretrieve?forum=AzureFunctions

Comment: Turns out the Azure moved to WindowsAzure.Storage 7.0 in the recent update and the Retrieve method signature had changed from the 4.3 version I had before.

Shared assemblies seem to be working well.

Answer (score 3):

What wound up working for me is putting the bin folder at the same level as the run.csx and then referencing it with no path, e.g.:

```
#r "MyAssembly.dll"
```

Comment: this is not exactly what the OP was trying to do - he wants to deploy a DLL that can be shared across many functions, which is why it's at parent level folder, not in the function folder.  You should be able to do that now (Feb 2017) by placing your shared DLLs in a wwwrooot\sharedbin folder

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to post comment due to low reputation, hence this 'answer' instead. 
I've put my custom dll under bin folder of similar folder structure as Andrew. But then faced the same issue:

```
2016-06-28T10:13:24.804 Unable to find assembly 'FunctionPOCLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Are you missing a private assembly file?2016-06-28T10:13:24.804 Function completed (Failure, Id=ac19dc2b-b5f1-4ffe-a290-747266b83935)
2016-06-28T10:13:24.835 Exception while executing function: Functions.QueueTriggerCSharp1. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ƒ-QueueTriggerCSharp1#ℛ*35133685-d255-4835-8282-acb5c5d9fca5#9-0: Could not load file or assembly 'FunctionPOCLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

In my code I'm parsing input value into POCO which was defined inside my custom assembly.

```
var rc  = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myQueueItem);
log.Info(rc.PropGuid.ToString());
```

Comment: make sure you reference the DLL at the top of your function csx like so:  #r "FunctionPOCLib.dll", then you can bring in the namespace with a "using" stmt.